# How to render a hierarchicl list of years and months with EF6 and MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework-6, nested-lists

I want to render a list of years and then the months under each year such that:

```
2012
   January
   February
   March
   Etc...
2013
   January
   February
   March
   Etc...
2014
   January
   February
   March
   Etc...
```

I use this to get the years back but don't know what to do next to show the months under the years:

```
Public Function SelectYearandMonth() As IEnumerable(Of ArchiveMonthYearViewModel)
  Dim posts
  posts = _postRepository.SelectAll.Where(Function(p) p.PostIsPublished).GroupBy(Function(p) New ArchiveMonthYearViewModel() With {.Year = p.PostDateCreated.Year}).Select(Function(a) a.Key).ToList
  Return posts
End Function
```

**Do I need a nested select or is groupbymany applicable here?**

And partial view:

```
 @ModelType IEnumerable(Of ArchiveMonthYearViewModel)
<hr />
<ul id="monthList" class="list-unstyled">
  @For Each item In Model
    @<li>@item.Year</li>    
  Next    
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you want the list of years and months?  Or do you only want the years and months where there are posts?  Your code seems to do the latter.

Comment: Years and months where there are posts.